# 100% Height Sections

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make sections of a website that have a 100% `width` and `height`. I see this all over the place (http://danedwards.me, http://tribalmedia.co.uk). Yes, these aren't completely filling the page, but you get the idea.

I don't want to use jQuery to create something that overrides scrolling and all that other jazz. I just want to have a simple HTML and CSS solution for this.

The big issue for me is that when I want to put content in the section, I want padding. The problem is that the section becomes bigger than 100%. So, I've taken code from other questions and pieced together a fiddle. When you scroll, notice the padding causes the section to be bigger than 100%.

The main question: **Am I creating the sections the right way? If so, how do you I fix the padding issue? If not, what should I do?**

Fiddle (my code): http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/W4EWC/

Full screen (here's where you'll notice the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/W4EWC/embedded/result/

Comment: well, you can put padding 3% and height 94% and width 94%.. that adds up to 100%

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to set the height properties to 100%. I probably don't understand the question, but I've changed them to auto. http://jsfiddle.net/W4EWC/39/ Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @Medda86 – 94 + 3 doesn't add to 100%. Either way, it doesn't work.

Comment: @9997 – the sections should fill up the screen.

Comment: well, when I went to school 3+3+94=100 lol

Comment: Whoops! I was only thinking of one padding. Yep, padding-top and bottom would add with the height to be a 100. That doesn't work though. The answer below is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your section CSS:

```
section {
    padding: 3%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/W4EWC/38/)**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

> border-box: The width and height properties include the padding and
>   border, but not the margin.